# React date-picker set a previous date from selected date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I just started learning front-end technologies (React) and facing an issue with [react date picker API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker).

Whenever I select a date from the UI, it displays correctly on the UI but when I bind the date to send it over to the server to save the record, it sends a previous date with a timestamp.

[image]

For example: If I select today's date i.e. 14 April 2022 from the UI, the actual date is bonded something like 13 April 2022T06:33:11.

```
dob: "2022-04-13T18:30:00.000Z"
```

I have tried to debug the issue but did find anything relevant, but when I console.log the date, it prints the same date as selected from the UI.

Here is the code that I implement for data picker.

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

const [dob, setDob] = useState("");

<DatePicker
  className="form-control" 
  minDate={new Date("1945/08/15")}
  maxDate={new Date()}
  selected={dob}
  onChange={(date) => setDob(date)}
  showMonthDropdown
  showYearDropdown
  dropdownMode="select"  

/>
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you check the Network tab on what data is being sent. It is possible that on server side you are deserialzing incorrectly to a different timezone or utc timezone.

Comment: Hi @RahulJujarey, yes I have checked the network tab, incorrect date is being sent from the front-end side. Even tried with adding locale property but still getting same error

Comment: The date `dob: "2022-04-13T18:30:00.000Z"` is  in UTC and it is same as `dob: "2022-04-14 00:00:00.000"` in IST. Please check the timezone of you application. You can convert it back to IST again and send to server.

Comment: @nkkumawat: Alright but if I set the date format to MM/dd/yyyy then why its set dob along with timestamp?

Comment: 1. I think it has something to do with day light savings. React-datepicker team should correct it through a new prop.
2. They should write little description with each prop.